# URL Rewrite Rule to remove www. for all URLs except for 1

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a working rule that removes www. for all urls coming in.  I have a webserivce that the redirect will change from a POST to a GET. I need to exclude the URL https://www.foo.net/WebServices/service.asmx from this rule.

I have looked at other solutions on SO with no success.

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Remove WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*"/>
              <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(foo\.net)" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily by adding a condition to "not match" (aka adding "negate='true'" ), something like this should work:

```
  <rules>
      <rule name="Remove WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.foo\.net$" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/WebServices/service\.asmx$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://foo.net/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
```